# R: How to select rows when column is in given range?

Tags: r

This is how my data looks like

```
> d[1,]
        Date sulfate nitrate ID
1 2003-01-01      NA      NA  1
>
```

Total observations

```
> dim(d)
[1] 772087      4
```

I want to get the rows where `ID` is in range `70:72` (this is coming from parameter)

What I do

```
d[d$ID==(70:71),]
```

What I get back is

```
Warning message:
In d$ID == (70:71) :
  longer object length is not a multiple of shorter object length
```

Comment: you should  use `%in%`

Comment: To clarify @agstudy 's comment, do `d[d$ID %in% 70:71, ]`.

Comment: @blakeoft consider posting this as an answer.

Answer (score 0):

Run `d[d$ID %in% 70:71, ]` to subset your data frame.